# Set div height to default in a jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have created a drop-down-menu, the html for the drop-down part basically looks like this:

```
<div class="menu-item">
  <!-- Menu title -->
  <div class="drop-down">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to animate this using jQuery-Code (with the easing-plugin), but the following Code does not work:

```
$(".menu-item").mouseenter(activate);
$(".menu-item").mouseleave(deactivate);

function deactivate()
{
  var dropdown = $(this).find("div.drop-down");
  dropdown.stop().animate(
    {height:     '0px'},
    {queue:       false,
     duration:    600,
     easing:      'easeOut'
    }
  );
}

function activate()
{
  var dropdown = $(this).find("div.drop-down");
  dropdown.stop().animate(
    {height:     'auto'},
    {queue:       false,
     duration:    600,
     easing:      'easeOut'
    }
  );
}
```

The message in the error console is: "Warning: Error in parsing value for 'height'.  Declaration dropped."

If I use "height: '100px'" or somthing similar in the `activate`-Function it works as expected. But for maintainability reasons i want the height to be calculated autmatically, so the drop-down adapts its size to its content.

How can this be achieved?

Greetings,
Jost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to use [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown) for this animation. Note that those functions accept easing functions.

Other option, if for some reason you need to use `animate` for this, you might want to do something like this in your `activate` function:

```
function activate(){
  var dropdown = $(this).find("div.drop-down");

  dropdown.css('height','auto')
          .hide()
          .stop()
          .animate(
             {height:     'auto'},
             {queue:       false,
              duration:    600,
              easing:      'easeOut'
          });
}
```

Comment: slideUp() and -Down() did the trick, thanks for this. There is a slight problem though: If the dropdown contains more than one line, it slides down the first line, but the immediately pops up the second line. Maybe this is due to some CSS settings.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be store the height value in the deactivate method and use it when activating. I do not think that jQuery supports animating a dimension property to a string value.

```
var menu_handler = (function(){
  var orig_height = 0;
  return {
    deactivate : function deactivate () {
      var dropdown = $(this).find("div.drop-down");
      orig_height = dropdown.height();
      dropdown.stop().animate(
        {height:     '0px'},
        {queue:       false,
         duration:    600,
         easing:      'easeOut'
        }
      );
    },
    activate : function activate () {
      var dropdown = $(this).find("div.drop-down");
      dropdown.stop().animate(
        {height:     orig_height},
        {queue:       false,
         duration:    600,
         easing:      'easeOut'
        }
      );
    }
  };
}

$(".menu-item").mouseenter(menu_handler.activate));
$(".menu-item").mouseleave(menu_handler.deactivate));
```

Comment: this should work great as long as the content inside `div.drop-down` doesn't change